# Comparison of Complete NTT and Incomplete NTT Multiplication

Tags: lattice-crypto

is the complete NTT is the fastest algorithm to multiply polynomials or there are hybrid versions that are faster than complete NTT multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anyone who has done precisely the comparison you want, but something that is likely of interest is [NTTRU](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/040.pdf).
At a high level, it is difficult to work with NTRU over power-of-two cyclotomics, which are the main ring people optimize NTTs over.
The linked work instead works over $\mathbb{Z}_{7681}[x]/(x^{768}-x^{384}+1)$.
This ring does not fully split, so the authors use an incomplete NTT (terminating in polynomial rings mod cubic polynomials) that they claim is roughly as fast as power-of-two cyclotomics (i.e. complete NTTs).

Comment: Yes! This article leads me to this question here. but theoretically the base multiplication has more operations than the complete NTTs